# Inno-setup: Store all user's choices in an INI file

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to store all the choices made by a user (or the default values, if the user did not change them) during installation in an .INI file. I know about the command-line option /LOADINF and /SAVEINF, but I would like to have a similar capability without depending on the command line. This would be used to keep settings in case of re-installation, but also to define a set of settings (that are defined by an administrator) to be used in multiple installations accross decentralized offices.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you are looking for.  You'll need a fair amount of code in your [code] section though.  I did something similar a number of years ago but I was only reading the INI.  I never wrote to the INI file. you should be able to write to it using SetIni* (SetIniString, SetIniBool, etc.) functions.  You can read the INI file using GetIni* functions.  Here's a quick sample I threw together that gives an idea:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{4CCA332F-C69B-48DF-93B4-145EB88A1BCB}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={code:GetDefaultDir}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\util\innosetup\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, "&", "&&")}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
var 
FinishedInstall : boolean;

function GetDefaultDir(def: string): string;
var
sInstallPath : string;
bRes : boolean;

begin
  sInstallPath := GetIniString('Common', 'TargetDir', ExpandConstant('{pf}') + '\myApp', ExpandConstant('{src}') + '\myappsetup.INI');
  Result := sInstallPath;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
     FinishedInstall := True;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var
bIni : boolean;
begin
if FinishedInstall then
  bIni := SetIniString('Common', 'TargetDir',ExpandConstant('{app}'), ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\myappsetup.INI');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Mirtheil, I got some good ideas from this. In order to use this, however, I need to know exactly which event procedures will let me access the user choices BEFORE the actual install starts. Also, how do I get access to the user choices on the standard dialogs (like the application directory or group).

Comment: The sample I gave above would set the application directory.  You could apply it to the program group by doing similar code for the "DefaultGroupName" which sets the constant {groupname}. Most of the standard dialogs store information in various constants.